# Cloudformation condition never evaluates to true

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create multiple instances based on a CFN Number Parameter with the following parameter and conditions.

```
Parameters:
  NumberOfInstances:
    Type: Number
    MinValue: 1
    MaxValue: 10
    Default: 1
    Description: >
      How many Edge Nodes do you want to launch in this Stack? (Min = 1, Max = 10)

Conditions:
  MoreThan1:
    !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 2], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 3], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 4], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 5], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 6], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 7], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 8], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 9], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 10] ]
  MoreThan2:
    !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 3], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 4], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 5], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 6], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 7], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 8], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 9], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 10] ]
  MoreThan3:
    !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 4], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 5], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 6], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 7], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 8], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 9], !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 10] ]
```

In the Resources section for the first instance (which is always created, but tagged with a different name format if NumberOfInstances is greater than 1)

```
  MyInstance01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !If [MoreThan1, !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-001',!Ref AWS::StackName ]
```

In the Resources section for the second instance I then have:

```
  MyInstance02:
    Condition: MoreThan1
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-002'
```

But the condition `MoreThan1` never seems to evaluate to true because neither the Instance Name tag is set correctly for the first instance, nor is the second instance created when NumberOfInstances is greater than 1.

In fact, none of the conditions seem to evaluate to true, regardless of the value of the `NumberOfInstances` parameter.

I assume that the Conditions are therefore not defined correctly, but what is wrong with them?

---

Update:

I have 'simplified' the conditions, but they still never evaluate to true.

The new conditions are:

```
Conditions:
  TwoOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 2], !Condition ThreeOrMoreInstances]
  ThreeOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 3], !Condition FourOrMoreInstances]
  FourOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 4], !Condition FiveOrMoreInstances]
  FiveOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 5], !Condition SixOrMoreInstances]
  SixOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 6], !Condition SevenOrMoreInstances]
  SevenOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 7], !Condition EightOrMoreInstances]
  EightOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 8], !Condition NineOrMoreInstances]
  NineOrMoreInstances: !Or [!Equals [NumberOfInstances, 9], !Condition TenOrMoreInstances]
  TenOrMoreInstances: !Equals [NumberOfInstances, 10] # Not actually ten OR MORE, but keeping same format makes easier to extend in future
```

with the appropriate changes in the Resources section:

```
Resources:
  MyEC2Instance01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: c5.large
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !If [TwoOrMoreInstances, !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-001',!Ref AWS::StackName ]
    ..etc...

  MyEC2Instance02:
    Condition: TwoOrMoreInstances
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: c5.large
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-002'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this happens because you are using `NumberOfInstances` **instead of** `!Ref NumberOfInstances` in your conditions. So you are just comparing literal string `"NumberOfInstances"` (not value of `NumberOfInstances` parameter) with different numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer - none of the conditions seem to evaluate to true, not just `MoreThan1`. Your fix would simplify the first condition, but all other conditions are failing as well (also see my update - I have simplified things significantly another way).